# Why a PGSQL graphical client can connect through SSH Tunnel and not me?

Tags: postgresql, ssh-tunnel

I have a PostgreSQL server which allow only local connexion.

I'm using "Navicat for PostgreSQL Lite" to do some admin operations. In this client, I configured a SSH Tunnel to my server. Everything works fine.

Today, I wanted to use another client which doesn't let me configure the SSH Tunnel inside. So, I tried to open a SSH Tunnel manually:

```
ssh -L 15021:myserver.com:5432 me@myserver.com
```

But when I tried to use it with the client, it says the connection is refused. In the SSH prompt, I've got this message.

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I tried

```
psql -h localhost -p 15021 db_name
```

Same error ...

I don't understand what magical stuff Navicat does that I don't do with my manual SSH Tunneling. I'm pretty certain that PostgreSQL listen on port 5432.

Thanks for any pointer or answer.

EDIT:

This is an attempt log with `LogLevel DEBUG`. I anonymized the hostname.

```
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype direct-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: server_request_direct_tcpip: originator ::1 port 64027, target myserver.com port 5432
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: connect_next: host myserver.com ([xxx.xx.xx.xxx]:5432) in progress, fd=9
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: channel 1: new [direct-tcpip]
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm direct-tcpip
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: error: connect_to myserver.com port 5432: failed.
Sep 13 14:57:23 myserver sshd[27793]: debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip, nchannels 2
```

Comment: Please enable `LogLevel DEBUG` in the server side, restart the `sshd` daemon and paste the output of a failed attempt in your question.

Comment: Have you tried other port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ssh -L 15021:myserver.com:5432 me@myserver.com

That's not the typical way of setting up a tunnel, because it's asking the remote SSH server to connect to PostgreSQL through its public IP address (`myserver.com`)

This leads to `Connection refused` because postgres doesn't listen on its public address. That's the usual and default case.

You probably meant to do:

```
 ssh -L 15021:localhost:5432 me@myserver.com
```

in this case SSH will route the db connections from **your** `localhost:15021`  to the `localhost:5432` **of the remote host**, which is presumably where the db is expecting connections.